# Class parameter in Faces Config

Tags: java, class, jsf, faces-config

Is there a way to pass a class into a property as a Class object?

i.e.

```
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>clazz</property-name>
        <value>java.lang.Double.class</value>
    </managed-property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. This is only possible if the class in question has a (default) no-arg constructor. The `java.lang.Double` doesn't have one. Also, in theory your construct is invalid. The following would have worked if you use a class with a (default) no-arg constructor at the place where `java.lang.Double` is been definied:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.Bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>clazz</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.Class</property-class>
        <value>#{clazz.class}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>clazz</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.lang.Double</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

in combination with

```
public class Bean {
    private Class<?> clazz; 

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public void setClazz(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

You really need to specify it as a `String` and make use of [`Class#forName()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain the `java.lang.Class` from it. Here's a kickoff example:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.Bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>className</property-name>
        <value>java.lang.Double</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

in combination with

```
public class Bean {

    private Class<?> clazz;

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public void setClassName(String name) {
        try {
            this.clazz = Class.forName(name);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal class name.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. But it will be realized as String. You can turn it into `Class` in your bean, wherever it's needed, using `Class.forName(clazz)`

You may try using `<property-class>java.lang.Class</property-class>`, but I'm not sure there is a converter for that built-in

Comment: @DD I think you are a bit hasty on the downvote button. This works, and not having seen your bean itself, I can't say more.

Comment: Apologies I should have been more clear in my original post. Will edit to make it more clear.